# how to solve fatal error of exhausted memory in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I uploaded an sql file of about 300k and I got this error each time I try to access phpmyadmin:
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 100663304 bytes) in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\Util.php on line 2302

I have tried so many methods to get over it, they did not work.
I tried increasing memory limit too.

so, I need a way to only drop the last file i had uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

That you are running this on MSWindows rather suggests its your local machine / you have admin privileges and that this is a machine you physically have access to. Explaining all the steps involved in reconfiguring your PHP and webserver installation would be push the boundaries of what is practical here. And its the wrong way to fix the problem - PHPMyAdmin isn't intended for bulk data imports.

Install mysql.exe (if you don't already have it on your system) and use that to import the data.

Comment: "Install mysqldump (if you don't already have it on your system) and use that to import the data." you don't import data with mysqldump it's export only.. for importing you need to use the mysql client program with the command `< file.sql` to import ..

Comment: Yes - I meant to say mysql (specifically mysql.exe) Thanks Raymond.